# Openssl equivalent to mcrypt_get_block_size

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, php-openssl, php-7.1

I am currently in the process of replacing Mcrypt with OpenSSL since Mcrypt will be deprecated in PHP 7.1. I need is a way to get the blocksize per algorithm like [`mcrypt_get_block_size()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php).

I am wondering if there is an equivalent function to `mcrypt_get_block_size()` but it's pretty badly documented can't seem to find it.

Comment: In OpenSSL, you create a context with `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`. Then, you call `EVP_CIPHER_block_size` to get the block size. Its documented in [`EVP_EncryptInit` man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_CIPHER_block_size.html). Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) and [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: okay nice that's exactly what i need how do i call this in php though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[php-openssl](/questions/tagged/php-openssl) unfortunately doesn't have an API that would give you the cipher blockSize. If you *really* need it, you'd have to hard-code the blockSize (per algorithm).

However, typical applications would only need to support a single encryption algorithm, and in that case you should already know what the block size is for your case.

And also, the only use cases I've had for `mcrypt_get_block_size()`, `mcrypt_enc_get_block_size()` is PKCS#7 padding, which OpenSSL *already does by default* for block cipher algorithms. So it may be the case that you don't need this at all.

Comment: The block size is needed to determine the IV size.

Comment: @zaph There's `openssl_cipher_iv_length()` for that.

Comment: I don't understand what's confusing about this ... IV is not the same thing as block size, and `openssl_cipher_iv_length()` is a function that PHP exposes.

Comment: I see your confusion: The IV size *is* the same as the block size. See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC).

Comment: GCM mode accepts arbitrary length IVs; ECB doesn't care about IVs (yes, I know it's bad); CTR effectively doesn't care about block size (as far as PHP APIs usage goes anyway) - your profile info suggests that you should know more about this. Even mcrypt has separate `get_iv_size`, `get_block_size` functions, not by accident. `ivSize` and `blockSize` may be equal in practically all cases the OP would experience, but are ultimately not the same thing. It's one thing if you didn't understand what I meant, but I don't appreciate you condescendingly implying "confusion" on my part.

Comment: in my case there is a dropdown where you can choose your encryption type since it needs to support some older onces aswell as new, sure it can be hardcoded but i hoped it could be done more dynamicly

Comment: @herriekrekel Sounds quite strange that you'd need such a thing, but if it works for you, you could do what @zaph suggests - treat ivSize and blockSize the same - and use `openssl_cipher_iv_length()` for it. They should be the same for every cipher supported by mcrypt, but I wouldn't rule out issues with the newer stuff in OpenSSL.

Comment: @Narf sounds good i will go with that wasn't to sure if it was the same thing in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

The following function can be used as a replacement for PHP >= 5.4.0.
It just bruteforces the block length out of `openssl_encrypt()`.

```php
if (!function_exists('openssl_cipher_block_length')) {
    /**
     * Returns the block length for a given cipher.
     *
     * @param string $cipher
     *      A cipher method (see openssl_get_cipher_methods()).
     *
     * @retval int
     *      The cipher's block length.
     *      Returns false if the actual length cannot be determined.
     *      Returns 0 for some cipher modes that do not use blocks
     *      to encrypt data.
     *
     * @note
     *      PHP >= 5.4.0 is required for this function to work.
     */
    function openssl_cipher_block_length($cipher)
    {
        $ivSize = @openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);

        // Invalid or unsupported cipher.
        if (false === $ivSize) {
            return false;
        }

        $iv = str_repeat("a", $ivSize);

        // Loop over possible block sizes, from 1 upto 1024 bytes.
        // The upper limit is arbitrary but high enough that is
        // sufficient for any current & foreseeable cipher.
        for ($size = 1; $size < 1024; $size++) {
            $output = openssl_encrypt(
                // Try varying the length of the raw data
                str_repeat("a", $size),

                // Cipher to use
                $cipher,

                // OpenSSL expands the key as necessary,
                // so this value is actually not relevant.
                "a",

                // Disable data padding: php_openssl will return false
                // if the input data's length is not a multiple
                // of the block size.
                //
                // We also pass OPENSSL_RAW_DATA so that PHP does not
                // base64-encode the data (since we just throw it away
                // afterwards anyway)
                OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,

                // Feed it with an IV to avoid nasty warnings.
                // The actual value is not relevant as long as
                // it has the proper length.
                $iv
            );

            if (false !== $output) {
                return $size;
            }
        }

        // Could not determine the cipher's block length.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like that:

```
$method = 'AES-256-CBC';
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
$block_size = strlen(openssl_encrypt('', $method, '', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
```

It's basically encrypting an empty string and, as the data will be padded to the block size, check the result length.

I've tested it with some different methods, and it seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach that might help you involves using this polyfill: [mcrypt_compat](https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat). A polyfill is a library that implements functionality which is not supported yet/anymore.

**Step 1:** install the library with Composer

```
composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat
```

**Step 2:** require Composer's autoloader at the top of the PHP script where you use the mcrypt functions (make sure the relative path is correct)

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

By now, you can use functions like `mcrypt_get_block_size()` in this PHP script

Answer (score 0):

txigreman this solution worked for me, i managed to change MCRYPT code to use OPENSSL 
this is my function to encrypt which replaced MCRYPT i mixed some code from MCRYPT and new code from openssl, while decrypt is not working but i can open payment page of provider and finish payment- thats what i needed and after it redirects me to success page, NeO.network.ae payment gateway

```
public $method = 'aes-256-cbc';

$this->EncryptedString                      = $this->encryptData($this->beforeEncryptionString, $this->merchantKey, $this->method);

    public function encryptData(string $data, string $key, string $method): string
    {
        $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv = 'YOUR_IV';
        $size               = strlen(openssl_encrypt('', $method, '', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
        $pad                = $size - ( strlen( $data ) % $size );
        $padtext            = $data . str_repeat( chr( $pad ), $pad );
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($padtext, $method, base64_decode( $key ), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

        $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);

        return $encrypted;
    }
```